# Vue.js props undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

When this code is executed, "undefined" is output.

Child component

```
export default {
  porps: [
    'idx'
  ],
  mounted () {
      console.log(this.idx)
  },
} //BambooPage.vue
```

Parent component

```
<template>
  <div class="bamboo">
    <bamboo-page v-bind:idx="index" v-if="show"></bamboo-page>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BambooPage from '@/components/Bamboo/Page/BambooPage.vue'
export default {
  name: 'bamboo',
  data: () => {
    return {
      show: false,
      index: 0
    }
  },
  components: {
    BambooPage
  },
  mounted () {
      this.index = 5
      this.show = true
  },
}
</script>
```

On Vue Devtools, has $attars "idx: 5" in child component.

How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo in word props)
    porps: [
    'idx'
  ]

Change to props